# Restrict access to Apigee Default URL

Tags: node.js, apigee

I have a set of APIs made using Node JS with a URL like this: https://api.mydomain.com/

I am using Apigee, so have set up a proxy like this: **https://mydomain.apigee.com/**

I want users to be able to access the APIs **only** through **https://mydomain.apigee.com/**

What do I do in my Node JS code to block access through the default https://api.mydomain.com/
URL, but not through **https://mydomain.apigee.com/**?

Do I need to check for an IP address, or authenticate with Apigee? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an IP whitelist in your Node stack to ensure inbound calls originate from only your Apigee services/proxy layer (Apigee proxy is the 'client' to your Node stack), but IP whitelisting is usually not considered enough security by today's standards. Thus, you can also use mTLS (two-way SSL) between Apigee and your Node stack and have your Node stack or its front-end TLS-termination layer validate (from a cert whitelist) the client TLS certificate being presented by Apigee's proxy layer upon establishing the connection to your back-end.